# POST 400 Bad Request Django

Tags: python, json, django, bad-request

My branch model has 4 primary keys which are unique together: ('branch_short_name', 'partner_short_name', 'tenant', 'contributor'). I would like to be able to create/ POST some objects with similar
'branch_short_name', 'partner_short_name', 'tenant' but then with a unique 'contributor'.
When doing that I get a 400 bad request error in postman. I don't know where the problem lies, in the model or in the serializer.

models.py

```
class Branch(models.Model):
additional_address1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
additional_address2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
branch_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
branch_short_name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255)
building = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
end_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
country_code = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
display_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
display_web = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
district = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
file_origin_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
filename = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
floor = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
business_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
house_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
import_file_number = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
contributor = models.CharField(max_length=255)
job_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
latitude = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
longitude = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
start_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
branch_hours = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
po_box = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
province = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
region = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
remarks = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
street = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
tenant = models.CharField(max_length=255)
updated = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
ranking = models.FloatField()
branch_type = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
branch_contact_text1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
branch_contact_text2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
email_address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
website = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
branch_hours_osm = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True, null=True)
partner_short_name = models.ForeignKey('Partner', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='partner_short_name')
features = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.
marketing_attribute_short_names = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.
marketing_attribute_values = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'branch'
    unique_together = (('branch_short_name', 'partner_short_name', 'tenant', 'contributor'),)
```

serializers.py

```
class BranchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Branch
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'])
def branch_list(request):
    # GET list of branchs, POST a new branch, DELETE all branchs

    if request.method == 'GET':
        branchlist = Branch.objects.all()[:10]
        branchlist_serializer = BranchSerializer(branchlist, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(branchlist_serializer.data, safe=False)
        # 'safe=False' for objects serialization


    elif request.method == 'POST':
        branch_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        branch_serializer = BranchSerializer(data=branch_data)
        if branch_serializer.is_valid():
            branch_serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(branch_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED) 
        return JsonResponse(branch_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/places$', views.branch_list),
    url(r'^api/placescount$', views.branch_count),
    url(r'^api/latestimport/(?P<contributor>\D+)$', views.latest_import),
    url(r'^api/partners$', views.partner_list),
    url(r'^api/partners/(?P<partner_short_name>[0-9]+)$', views.partner_detail),
    url(r'^api/places/(?P<branch_short_name>[0-9]+)$', views.branch_detail),
    url(r'^api/places/(?P<branch_short_name>[0-9]+)/(?P<contributor>\D+)$' , views.branch_from_contributor),
]
```

[image: 1]

Comment: "similar" typically does not mean "exactly the same".  Did you actually mean that the names are identical?

Comment: Some values of the attributes (primary keys) are the same, as a duplicate.